# Why my TableView not updating cells which are fetched from database?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have TableView and every cell contains one reservation fetched from Firestore. I added refresh controller but no data reloads. I don't know where can be a problem. When I changed one reservation status for eg. canceled in Firebase it changes but in tableview after reloads no UI label change to "canceled". I must to display another controller and go back to update UI label in cell.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    reservationsTableView.delegate = self
    reservationsTableView.dataSource = self
    navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    searchReservations = Reservations
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh(send: )), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    reservationsTableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    loadReservations()
    
}
@objc func refresh(send: UIRefreshControl)
{
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.loadReservations()
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        self.reservationsTableView.reloadData()
    }
}


}
func loadReservations()
{
    Reservations = []
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let userCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("Users")
    let thisUserDoc = userCollection.document(uid)
    let snapshot = thisUserDoc.collection("Reservations").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let e = error {
            print(e)
        }
        else
        {
            if let snapshotDocuments = querySnapshot?.documents
            {
                for doc in snapshotDocuments
                {
                    let data = doc.data()
                    //   let rid = doc.documentID
                    if let Time = data["Time"] as? String, let Date = data["Date"] as? String, let Guests = data["Guests"] as? String, let RestaurantName = data["RestaurantName"] as? String, let Name = data["Name"] as? String, let Status = data["Status"] as? String, let Phone = data["Phone"] as? String, let Id = data["Id"] as? String, let RestaurantId = data["RestaurantID"] as? String, let Id2 = data["Id2"] as? String, let guestId = data["GuestId"] as? String
                    {
                        let newReservation = Reservation(id: Id, userId: guestId, id2: Id2,restaurantId: RestaurantId ,restaurantName: RestaurantName, name: Name, phone: Phone, guests: Guests, time: Time, date: Date, status: Status)
                        self.Reservations.append(newReservation)
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.reservationsTableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return searchReservations.count
}
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.reusableCellReservationsC, for: indexPath) as! ReservationCellC
        
        cell.guestName.text = searchReservations[indexPath.row].name
        cell.contact.text = searchReservations[indexPath.row].phone
        cell.reservationTime.text = searchReservations[indexPath.row].time
        cell.reservationDate.text = searchReservations[indexPath.row].date
        cell.reservationGuets.text = searchReservations[indexPath.row].guests
        cell.reservationStatus.text = searchReservations[indexPath.row].status
        cell.cancelBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        
        
        cell.cancelBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnCanceledCellTapped(sender: )), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.confirmBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnConfirmedCellTapped(sender: )), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.lateBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnLateCellTapped(sender: )), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Is `self.Reservations.append(newReservation)` called? Are the UITableViewDataSource methods called? What's their code?

Comment: I added cells data source code.

Comment: @BranislavFekeč you are adding in `self.Reservations.append(newReservation)` whereas you are passing `searchReservations.count` in number of rows. Probably you would need to append to `searchReservations` or need to pass `self.Reservations` count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's this line

```
 searchReservations = Reservations
```

By the way you are appending reservations as below

```
self.Reservations.append(newReservation)
```

But you are having row count as

```
searchReservations.count
```

This is wrong. It has to be  `return Reservations.count` or you must append values as `self.searchReservations.append(newReservation)`

Comment: Yeah It was the problem. I solve it with this code. Thank you so much.

 self.Reservations.append(newReservation)
 self.searchReservations = self.Reservations